# Cannot find module '…/models/user' nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, mern

I just found a cool project that I want to clone and explore, but I getting this weird error.
I tried to read some similar solution here but couldn't find any.

after executing npm start,  i getting this error.
[image]

You can clone the project from here.
https://github.com/didinj/mern-stack-authentication

I have installed as described.
[image]

Comment: please copy/paste the code in your question instead of giving screenshots

Answer (score 1):

From the Err message:

> Error: Cannot find module '../models/user'
>   It simply cannot resolved the path to User.js file.

In your auth.js and passport.js file rename or change this import line of code

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```

to

```
var User = require('../models/User');
```

I notice the file name is `User.js` not `user.js`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to execute

`npm install`

This will install all of project's dependencies.

Comment: I did it, as explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name is `User` not `user`, so please update `auth.js` and replace

`var User = require("../models/user");`

with

`var User = require("../models/User");`

Comment: Hey, Thank you it helped! I did it and it fixed it immediately/

Comment: @שגיאשלום Glad to help, Please tick the answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find the module named `../models/user` because your file name is `User.js` not 'user.js' inside Models folder.

you can either change the name of the file from 'User.js' to 'user.js'

or

you can change the `require('../models/user')` to `require('../models/User')` in your 2 files- auth.js and passport.js